# How to search in SQL for cloumn with asterisk?

Tags: mysqli

I try to create advanced search to my database.
I want to do something like that: if the user type for search = `overf**w`
and I have in my database an cloumn that his value = `overflow` - show him.
this my code:

```
$name = str_replace('*', '_', $name);
SELECT name FROM table WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
```

its not working, I dont know what the problem.

Comment: do you mean when you search overf**w then the $name is overf__w and then you want the query to return overflow?

Comment: @pravinnavle no, I want if user wrote in input `overf**w` and I have in my database `overflow` - return overflow

Answer (score 0):

You can't use LIKE in this situation, you need to use REGEXP() to do a wildcard search. Replace * or ** with `.*`. To only return names that starts with the given value use `^` at the beginning of the regular expression

```
SELECT name 
FROM actors 
WHERE name REGEXP('^overf.*w')
```

I don't know php but your $name parameter should be set like this (in pseudo code)

```
$name = '^' + replace($name, '**', '.*')
```

Comment: But I cant do what you wrote, because I get the value from user input

Comment: That was just an example, you should use `?` as in your code but for the $name variable you need to replace `**`with `.*`

Comment: I do what you said, but I have a problem. I want to search in sql only for value that start in the user input, not contain the user input

Comment: @John, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: for example: if user type overf* *w, I want to get values from sql like: overflow, overflow its forum, overflow the best. and **do not get values like that:** my overflow, what is it overflow

I want to get only what beginning with overflow

Comment: Thank you so much. I have one more question. its possible to limit the values from sql length by the asterisk I wrote? for example: b** will return only values that match to this string (have length = 3 and start with b) like bus, big

Comment: Yes you use a range {3,3} instead of the * after ., `.{3,3}`. If you want to use more specialised or advanced searches I suggest you read up on regular expressions, they are in some way supported in most languages and advanced text editors for searching. It's a really useful tool to have as a developer

Comment: What is it mean range? can you give me example please?

Comment: `$length = strlen($name);
$replace = ".*{" . $length . "," . $length . "}";
$name = '^' . str_replace('?', $replace, $name);`
this what I do, its not work

Comment: This is an sql question and not php, using for instance `REGEXP('^overf.{2,2}w')` will find names starting with 'overflow'

Comment: Sorry, its not work. its show only what start with, but not only what have the strlen. I mean if I wrote `b??` its show what start with `b` but its show what his strlen his not = 3

Comment: You have asked a question and I have answered it and tried to help you beyond what is expected, now show some respect for that and appreciate the help you have gotten. Last help from me,  REGEXP('^b.{2,2}$') will match 'big', 'bus' etc. Note the $ at the end